# Prove that $\max _{z \leq 1} |az^n+b|=|a|+|b|, a,b \in \mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that $\max _{|z| \leq 1} |az^n+b|=|a|+|b|, a,b \in \mathbb C$

We'll get the maximum of the function $|f(z)|=|az^n+b|$ at $|z|=1$.

So what I tried doing is setting $z=e^{it}$, $a=r_1e^{i \alpha}, b=r_1e^{i\beta}$, plugged it in $|az^n+b|$.

Eventually, I got $\max _{|z| = 1} \sqrt{r_1^2+2r_1r_2cos(\alpha+nt)+r_2^2}$. It would be very comfortable to say we get the max of that expression when $\alpha+nt=0$, and then get desired result - but I couldn't justify this - for instance when $r_1$ or $r_2$ are negative...

Any assistance will be great!

Comment: I think the statement is only correct if you replace $\max$ with $\sup$. That it's *an* upper bound follows from the triangle inequality. That you can get arbitrarily close (i.e. the $\sup$ property) follows from the result that if $\theta \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, then $\{ m \theta \mod{1} : m \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is dense in $(0, 1)$. As for the $\max$ property, it would seem that if $\arg b \not \in 2 \pi \mathbb{Q}$, then you will never *attain* the supremum.

Comment: Also, you can assume without loss of generality ("WLOG") that $r_{1}, r_{2} \geq 0$.

Comment: Why can I assume this?

Comment: Well, suppose $a = r e^{i \theta}$, where $r < 0$. Then you might as well just rewrite it as $a = r' e^{i (\theta')} $, where we set $\theta' = \theta + \pi, r' = -1$. To see this, consider that $e^{x + y} = e^{x} e^{y}$. Then
\begin{align*}
r' e^{i \theta'} & = (- r) e^{i (\theta + \pi)} \\
& = ( - 1) * r e^{i \theta} * e^{i \pi} \\
& = ( - 1) * r e^{i \theta} * (- 1) \\
& = (- 1 * - 1) r e^{i \theta} \\
& = r e^{i \theta}.
\end{align*}

So it's probably going to be more convenient to make the assumption.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: But if the problem above is written correctly, then it's wrong if we *only* allow $z$ to be real. If we suppose instead that $|z| \leq 1$, then we're okay, and you've got the result, but if it's supposed to be $z \leq 1$, then as I said, I think the statement is false.

Comment: I wrote it wrong, should be $|z| \leq 1$. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, we always have $\max_{|z| \le 1} |a z^n + b| \le |a| + |b|$ from the triangle inequality.

To see what exactly is the maximum, let's simplify a bit. If $a = 0$ or $b = 0$ the result is obvious, so assume $a \ne 0$ and $b \ne 0$. Denote $c = -\frac{b}{a} \ne 0$, then

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\max_{|z| \le 1} |a z^n + b| &= |a| \cdot \max_{|z| \le 1} |z^n - c| \\
&= |a| \cdot \max_{|z'| \le 1} |z' - c|
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
The second equality is just a change of variable $z' = z^n$. Now we're looking for the point $z_0$ in the unit disc $D = \{z, \, |z| \le 1\}$ that is the farthest from $c$. If you draw a picture, you'll see that point is in the intersection of the unit circle $C = \{z, \, |z| = 1\}$ with the line joining $0$ and $c$ "diametraly opposite" to $c$ (there are two such points, but one of them is clearly further from $c$) and that $|z_0-c| = 1 + |c|$. So we get as expected

$$\max_{|z| \le 1} |a z^n + b| = |a| \cdot (1+|c|) = |a|+|b|$$

Comment: Great, thank you. Well explained... Thanks @abel as well for your help

Comment: Very pretty, ***endorsed!!!***

Answer (score 4):

by triangle inequality, you have $$|az^n + b| \le |a||z|^n+|b| \le  |a| + |b| \text{ if } |z| \le 1.$$  therefore $$   \max _{z \leq 1} |az^n+b|=|a|+|b|, a,b \in \mathbb C$$

$\bf p.s.$ the equality occurs when $|z| = 1$ and $arg(az^n)= arg(b).$  if $a = 0,$ then there is nothing to do.

in the case $a \neq 0,$  we have $$\arg(a) + n \arg(z) = \arg(b) \to \arg(z) = \frac{\arg(b) - \arg(a)}{n} $$ so that $$z^n = e^{i(\arg(b) - \arg(a))}, az^n = |a|e^{i\arg(b)}, az^n + b = (|a|+|b|)e^{i\arg(b)}$$ and finally $$|az^n + b| = |a| + |b| \text{ where } z = e^{i\left(\frac{\arg(b) - \arg(a)}{n} \right) }.$$

Comment: Why is it safe to use the triangle inequality? Why can't it be that it's just bigger ?

Comment: @Henas,  you can always use triangle inequality. in a triangle, every side is smaller than the sum of the other two side. if the triangle has sides $a, b, a+b,$ then certainly $|a + b| < |a| + |b|.$  that is what i used.

Comment: But if $|az^n+b| \leq |a|+|b|$, it doesn't automatically follow that $|az^n+b|=|a|+|b|$. That is what I don't understand

Comment: @abel - Shouldn't that be a $| a + b | \leq |a| + |b|$?

Comment: @Henas,  do you see that $|az^n| = |a||z|^n \le |a|$  if $|z| \le 1.$

Comment: yes, but being able to "ignore" the $b$ is what i don't get. Can't $b$ have a value so that $max |az^n+b| \neq |a|+|b|$? What grantees me that the function get this value? Sorry for all of my questions...

Comment: @Henas, just add $|b|$ to the inequality in my previous comment.

Comment: @abel:  Hello again, my friend!  Question:  it's clear from what you've done that $\vert az^n +  b \vert \le \vert a \vert + \vert b \vert$ for $\vert z \vert \le 1$, but how do you show $\vert a \vert + \vert b \vert$ is actually *attained* for some $z_0$ with $\vert z_0 \vert \le 1$?  If it's not then the maximum absolute value is *strictly* less than $1$.  As ever, Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis, thanks for keeping me honest. see the edit.

Comment: You're more than welcome, sir!  And I'll trust your vigilance to protect my integrity as well!  Very nice post script, I might add; ***endorsed!!!***