# Maximum of a complex function without using derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $a, b \in \mathbb C$ and $n \in \mathbb N$. Calculate $\max{|az^n+b|}$ with $|z|=1$, and find all the values of $z$ in which the function has its maximum.

I could calculate the value of the maximum, and it is $|a|+|b|$. Then, I thought that $z=1^{1/n}$ were the values in which the function reaches its maximum; nonetheless, I was wrong.

How can I get those values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When computing the maximum, have you seen some condition for $z$ so the maximum is attained?

Comment: if $b=0$ any $|z|=1$ works, same if $a=0$; assuming $ab \ne 0$ take $z$ a root of order $n$ of $\frac{b/a}{|b|/|a|}$ so $z^n=kb/a, k= \frac{|a|}{|b|}>0$ so $|az^n+b|=|kb+b|=(k+1)|b|=(\frac{|a|}{|b|}+1)|b|=|a|+|b|$

Comment: Did you use the triangle inequality? Do you know when *equality* holds in the triangle inequality?

Comment: Compare [Prove that $\max _{z \leq 1} |az^n+b|=|a|+|b|, a,b \in \mathbb C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1313843/42969).

Comment: Martin, I have already proven that equality. That was the only part I could do, and I used the condition in which the equality holds.

Comment: Conrad after using what you have done, hpw do I obtain the values of $z$?